# WP7 application submission: do I have to embed images?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have to submit my WP7 app to the Marketplace. The app loads at runtime some images that are under the Images folder. They have the `copy to output directory` to `Do Not Copy` and I've seen that if I open the XAP file they are not included. If I see the app on my test phone it runs fine but I am not sure how to build and submit my app and would like to avoid problems in submission. Can anyone help me to understand how to correctly build and submit my project?

Comment: Uninstall the app from your dev phone, Clean the solution in VS and then try to deploy it. Does it still include the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 places you can put images to view in your app:

1. as content in the XAP
2. as resources embedded in assemblies
3. on the web

Having files set to "copy to output directory" will have no impact on what is deployed to or can be viewed on the phone.